# How to fill a shield data array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a food app. I would have children of my food which are my ingredients (menu = salami, ingredient = bbq...)

This is my data:

```js
products: [
    {id: 0, name: 'Salami', price: '8', hour: '', timCook: '',
      supp:[
      {id: 1123, name: 'fromage', price: '5', hour:'' },
      {id: 11234, name: 'bbq', price: '10', hour:'' }
    ], selected: []},
```

So, I have salami which has 2 ingredients and this salami is an empty array. When the user chooses his/her menu, I fill the empty array with the ingredient(s) he chose using this function :

```js
for(let supp of result.data.values){
    console.log(supp);
    //  this.cartService.addProducts(test); // ajoute en temps que produit
    products.selected.push(supp); // ajoute dans le tableau des item selectionner
    console.log(products);
}
```

In my shopping cart, I want to save the salami item with the chosen (by the user) ingredient in the selected array. 
For this, I save the item with the selected array in a new array, then, I clear the first array.

```js
for (let obj of items) { selected[obj.id] = { ...obj, count: 1 };
    a.push(selected[obj.id])
    obj.selected = [];
}
```

When I clear the selected array of the item, it also clears the selected array of the `a` array. So, how to only clear the selected array of the item and not the one which is saved in `a`?

It's a hard problem that is complicated to explain properly for me because I'm not english.

Thank's to all people who will help me!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When I clear the selected array of the item, it clears too the selected array of the a array. So, how to only clear the selected array of the item and not the one which is saved in a ?

Comment: Please try to create a minimal reproducible example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - provide a working code snippet and describe desired outcome or problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you are trying to achieve. What I understand is that the user can choose his menu and customize with some optional ingredients (like a Subway sandwich?).

What I would advise is to clearly split your data (i.e. the choices available) and what the user puts in its cart (i.e. input data).

Since you tagged your question with Angular/TypeScript, I would define TypeScript interfaces to help think about your data structure:

```
interface Ingredient {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  // In your code, you used strings for the following properties
  // but I think number would better fit (if you wish to sum, multiply, etc).
  price: number; 
  hour: number;
}

interface Menu {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number; 
  hour: number;
  timCook: number;
  supp: Ingredient[]; // An array of ingredients
}
```

You can then declare your base data like this:

```
// An array of Menu
const products: Menu[] = [
  {
      id: 0, name: 'Salami', price: 8, hour: null, timCook: null,
      supp:[
        { id: 1123, name: 'fromage', price: 5, hour: null },
        { id: 11234, name: 'bbq', price: 10, hour: null },
      ],
  },
];
```

Fine. Now, how to store what the user selected? We don't need to store every properties again (single source of truth). We just keep a reference to it : luckily, we have `id` for that. Let's define some interfaces:

```
interface MenuSelection {
  id: number; // Id. of the Menu the user selected
  supp: number[]; // Array of Ingredients id. the user selected
}

type Cart = MenuSelection[]; // The shopping cart is an array of MenuSelection
```

And now the logic:

```
const cart: Cart = [] // Start with empty cart

// Let's say your user selected Menu 0 and Ingredient 1123
// You'll have to wire with your interface to build such object
const menuSelection: MenuSelection = {
  id: 0,
  supp: [1123],
};

// Add a selection to the Cart
cart.push(menuSelection);
```

You can quite easily then build methods to retrieve the full `Menu` and `Ingredient` from the selected ids. if you want to show what's inside the shopping cart.

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginning, to me it appears to be complex, I'm trying that though.

Comment: Yeah, it's exaclty what  I want to do

Comment: I successfully do that in my code and all is working ! But I don't know how to retrieve the menu with just the ids

Comment: We could help you more if you provide us your code. You can use this [template on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) ; it's an online editor with a starter Angular project where you can copy/paste relevant parts of your code.